# Creating an array of SelectOption Lists

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Im trying to set up an online test, using a visualforce page that pulls data from 3 objects in salesforce `COPE_Tests__C`, `COPE_Questions__C`, and `COPE_Options__c`.  Once the user selects the specific test, I thought I would be able to make a call like this to get all the other data:

```
questions = [select id, name, question_body__c, 
(select id, name, option_body__c from COPE_options__r order by name ASC)
from COPE_questions__c where COPE_test__c = :tid];
```

And then use `apex:repeat` and `apex:selectRadio/apex:selectOption` to generate the actual test form.  But for some reason it would not render the radioboxes.  So it would seem I need to create selectOption lists and then use apex:selectOptions.  But im not sure how to set this up .  How can I have it create a public `list<selectOption>` automatically for each question?

Is there a way to set up an array of `list<selectOption>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about creating it automatically but going over your question object in a loop should be pretty easy, something over the lines of

```
List<List<SelectOption> options = new List<List<SelectOption>;
for(COPE_Questions__C q : questions){
    List<SelectOption> list = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(COPE_options__r op : q.COPE_options__r){
         list.add(new SelectOption(op.id, op.option_body__c);
    }
    options.add(list);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think thats what im looking for, but how do I identify which list belongs to which question?

Comment: Also, I seem to be getting a error on the third line: "Compile Error: unexpected token: 'List' at line XX column 4"

Comment: I fixed the compilation error. For identifying list to question you better of use a map from Id to list

Comment: Thanks so much, I realized your code was enough and I didnt need the Map, I just didnt understand how to use it at first.  here is what I ended up needing to do: `public List<List<SelectOption>> options {get;set;}` then `options = new List<List<SelectOption>>();
    for(COPE_Questions__C q : questions){
        List<SelectOption> l = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(COPE_options__c op : q.COPE_options__r){
            l.add(new SelectOption(op.id, op.option_body__c));
        }
        options.add(l);
    }`

Comment: and for the page: `<apex:variable var="count" value="{!0}" />
<apex:repeat value="{!questions}" var="q">
{!q.name}
<apex:repeat rows="1" first="{!count}" value="{!options}" var="op">
<apex:selectRadio >
<apex:selectOptions value="{!op}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectRadio>
</apex:repeat>
<apex:variable var="count" value="{!count+1}"/>
</apex:repeat>`